# Raster Clipper Location - QGIS 2.18.20

Tags: qgis, raster

Does anyone know where the Raster Clipper tool went in QGIS 2.18.20?

It used to be under Raster->Extraction->Clipper.

Comment: It should still be in the same menu location.

Comment: Ensure the `GdalTools` plugin is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The clipper tool location did not change. It remains in the same location Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper:

[image]

If you cannot see it, there might be something wrong happened during installation/update of QGIS software. Try to reinstall QGIS again and if it did not solve the issue, then uninstall QGIS completely and reinstall it again.

Comment: Yes I think this has happened (argh). I'll have to try an uninstall/reinstall process. What a pain.

Comment: Some of the tools in QGIS are actually plugins, and in a new install they're disabled by default. Check the plugin manager to see if that's the case for the Raster Clipper.

Comment: I am unable to find anything in the plugins relating to Raster Clipper. A re-install didn't fix it. And i'd really like to not uninstall.

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Comment: As mentioned in comments earlier in May, you should have checked that "GDAL Tools" is enabled in your plugin manager. The raster clipper is included in this core plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it with all of your help. I completely removed the QGIS installation with AppCleaner.app (free application). Re-installed and all is ok now. Rater clipper tools is where it used to be (Raster->Extraction->Clipper). Thanks guys.

Comment: It is better to accept my answer as it helped you to solve the problem :)

Comment: Right - thank you - but I wanted to mention the AppCleaner.app was required to get all files off of the machine.